# Call/Run VBA Macro through Angular

Tags: excel, angular, vba, angular6

I am stuck while calling the macro of excel from angular. I am using Spreadsheets ( https://www.grapecity.com/en/blogs/how-to-import-and-export-excel-spreadsheets-in-angular ) to load Excel sheet.

With the help of that I am able to open my macro enabled excel file in browser. But after opening I need to run one specific macro which has some arguments through angular 6.

app.html

```
<div class='maincontainer'>
<gc-spread-sheets [hostStyle]="hostStyle" 
(workbookInitialized)="workbookInit($event)">
</gc-spread-sheets>
<div class='loadExcelInput'>
<p>Open Excel File</p>
<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple id="jsonFile" accept=".xlsm" (change)="onFileChange($event)" />
</div>
<div class='exportExcel'>
<p>Save Excel File</p>
<button (click)="onClickMe($event)">Save Excel!</button>
</div>
</div>
```

app.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as GC from '@grapecity/spread-sheets';
import * as Excel from '@grapecity/spread-excelio';
import '@grapecity/spread-sheets-charts';
import {saveAs} from 'file-saver';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
spreadBackColor = 'aliceblue';
hostStyle = {
width: '95vw',
height: '80vh'
};
  private spread: GC.Spread.Sheets.Workbook;
  private excelIO;
  constructor() {
   this.excelIO = new Excel.IO();
  }
  workbookInit(args) {
    const self = this;
    self.spread = args.spread;
    const sheet = self.spread.getActiveSheet();

    sheet.getCell(0, 0).text('Test Excel').foreColor('blue');
    sheet.getCell(1, 0).text('Test Excel').foreColor('blue');
    sheet.getCell(2, 0).text('Test Excel').foreColor('blue');
    sheet.getCell(3, 0).text('Test Excel').foreColor('blue');
    sheet.getCell(0, 1).text('Test Excel').foreColor('blue');
    sheet.getCell(1, 1).text('Test Excel').foreColor('blue');
    sheet.getCell(2, 1).text('Test Excel').foreColor('blue');
    sheet.getCell(3, 1).text('Test Excel').foreColor('blue');
    sheet.getCell(0, 2).text('Test Excel').foreColor('blue');
    sheet.getCell(1, 2).text('Test Excel').foreColor('blue');
    sheet.getCell(2, 2).text('Test Excel').foreColor('blue');
    sheet.getCell(3, 2).text('Test Excel').foreColor('blue');
    sheet.getCell(0, 3).text('Test Excel').foreColor('blue');
    sheet.getCell(1, 3).text('Test Excel').foreColor('blue');
    sheet.getCell(2, 3).text('Test Excel').foreColor('blue');
    sheet.getCell(3, 3).text('Test Excel').foreColor('blue');

  }

  onFileChange(args) {
    const self = this, file = args.srcElement && args.srcElement.files && args.srcElement.files[0];
    if (self.spread && file) {
     // var aa = self.excelIO.GetApplication();
       self.excelIO.open(file, (json) => {
        self.spread.fromJSON(json, {});
        setTimeout(() => {
          alert('load successfully');
        }, 0);
      }, (error) => {
        alert('load fail');
       });
     }
  }
  onClickMe(args) {
    const self = this;
     const filename = 'exportExcel.xlsx';
    const json = JSON.stringify(self.spread.toJSON());
    self.excelIO.save(json, function (blob) {
      saveAs(blob, filename);
  }, function (e) {
      console.log(e);
  });
  }
}
```

After Alert of loading excel file, I want to run macro of that file from .ts 
Please suggest solution or any other library which satisfy my requirement.

Comment: I hardly believe you can call a VBA macro in a Excel file just using Angular and without Excel. There needs to be an application that is able to execute the VBA code. Usually that is Excel. I'm pretty sure that Angular has no VBA interpreter built in and therefore cannot execute VBA at a all. To run VBA code within an Excel file you (usually) need Excel.

Comment: Even Office 365 doesn't support VBA when executed in Browser.

Comment: You can try something with VBScript, not with VBA, for Angular.

Comment: @Vityata Does this really work out of the box with VBScript? I thought it would still need Windows as operating system and the Microsoft Office Object Library (which means Excel installed)?

Comment: Thanks to all of you for your suggestions. I agree an application is needed to execute VBA macro.

Comment: @RenukaShinde So then use Excel I suggest.

Comment: @PEH Any idea/library to get Excel Application through angular 6 ?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ - not out of the box, but the chances to do something with VBScript from Angular were a bit higher than with VBA.